# ¿Cómo puedo agregar elementos a un ListBox con DataSource?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Mi problema es que quiero modificar un ListBox con DataSource pero me sale la excepción: "**No se puede modificar la colección items cuando está establecida la propiedad datasource**".
Algo así quiero hacer:

```
        List<string> lists = listBox1.Items.OfType<string>().ToList();
        lists.Add(TextoUsar.Text);
        listaNotas.DataSource = lists;
```

Comment: tenes que modificar la lista con la que alimentas el datasource y volver a asignarlo

Comment: cómo se haría eso?

Comment: Debes actualizar la tabla con la que está enlazada ese listbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ACTUALIZACION:

Tu origen de datos es listaNotas. Por lo que quieres agregar mas elementos a este control.

```
//Se obtiene del origen. Estamos obteniendo los datos que tiene actualmente
List<string> lists = listaNotas.Items.OfType<string>().ToList();
//Agregamos mas elementos a la lista que declaramos anteriormente
lists.Add(TextoUsar.Text);
//Se pueden agregar o eliminar elementos ya que estamos trabajando con una lista.

//Asignamos la lista al control listaNotas
listaNotas.DataSource = lists;
```

No se puede modificar los datos de origen ya cargados, lo que podrías realizar es obtener esos datos, agregar el elemento y volver a asignar los elementos al origen del ListBox.

Ejemplo:

```
//Esta es mi objeto Actividad
public class Actividad
{
    public long IdActividad { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
}


//Actividad es un tipo Objeto
List<Actividad> listActividadView = lstFavoritos.Items.OfType<Actividad>().ToList();
//Asignas el nuevo elemento a la lista que obtuvimos anteriormente
listActividadView.Add(objActividad);
//Y lo vuelvo a cargar los datos en el listBox
lstFavoritos.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
lstFavoritos.ValueMember = "IdActividad";
lstFavoritos.DataSource = listActividadView;
```

Espero y esto te de una idea.

Comment: Consulta, qué es "ObjActividad"? Es el objeto de la clase? Si es así cómo agrego un elemento que no tiene que ver con el DataSource o una clase? Perdón si no me explico bien

Comment: El "objActividad" es un objeto de la clase Actividad, y es la que estamos agregando a la lista ya que desde un inicio declaramos una variable de tipo List<Actividad> y solo podremos añadir elementos de esa clase. El ListBox vincula una colección de elementos únicos, es decir, el control ListBox solo puede tener datos de un mismo tipo ya sean primitivos (int, string, etc) o de clase. Asi seria con un int por ejemplo: List<int> listActividadView = lstFavoritos.Items.OfType<int>().ToList(); y agregarias listActividadView .Add(10)

Comment: Vale, última pregunta, cuándo establezco el nuevo datasource el antiguo hace que los items desaparezcan y solo queda el item que agregué, cómo soluciono eso?

Comment: Podrías agregar el código que estas empleando. Puedes editar tu pregunta y agregarlo.

Comment: ya lo hice, espero te sirva para ayudarme

Comment: Edite la respuesta espero sea lo que buscas.